# How to supply JSON to React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Forewarning, I know little about React.JS.  I see it's mainly used to build components on the UI side.  The examples I found online are built using static JSON in the page itself.

What is the preferred method for making that API call to get the JSON data using React, or should I simply call my API using AJAX and pass the JSON data to React?

Comment: Okay thanks Benjamin.  I'll just use a standard jQuery Ajax call.  That's honestly what I thought it just didn't jump out at me.  If you want to put your comment in an answer format I'll accept it.  I think it's a relevant question for React newbie's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what sort of answer you're expecting here but React is not concerned with how you fetch the data.

React is just virtual DOM and components, it's completely unrelated to that part of your app. Facebook do [have some ideas](http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html) on how data should flow throughout your app with react but you have no obligation to their ideas of design.

So yes - you can for instance call your API using AJAX and pass the JSON data to react.

Comment: If you're referring to how one might load data in an isomorphic react app, a common approach seems to be to load JSON in a script tag from the server and optionally bootstrap the app with the data. Any server rendered components would just keep their initial data considering the checksum would be equal when rendering again on the client.

Comment: @cameronjroe isomorphism is between two entities (intuitively A and B are isomorphic if they're the same up to a name change) you're using that word wrong. I'm just saying here how one might interact with JSON data with react and the answer is that it's orthogonal to React which is concerned with the presentation logic and not with server-side calls. A react app using Angular and a react app built with flux architecture for instance would address this problem completely differently.

Comment: Yes, but isomorphism in regards to loading data with React for example presents a challenge of managing this.props. This is the only reason I point out that a preferred way to re-render that data is via a JSON object being loaded into a script tag. How the data loads beyond first page load is the choice of the developer.

Comment: @cameronjroe that word you keep using. I don't think it means what you think it means...

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/spikebrehm/building-isomorphic-apps-jsconfasia-2014 and a buddy of mine at Yahoo would +1 exactly what I said.